# 3.0 Crashes upon Motion Track

Tags: import, tracking

I'm having a problem regarding Blender 3.0 . when I import a footage to motion track blender crashes , it only prefetches half the footage and upon reaching the half where it didn't buffer it crashes.
Anyone else facing similar problem? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.